# Split a text file in Python by number of lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a txt file in below format and i want to split this file in such a way that it split the file after 4th line in one list list.

Input file:

```
1 A
2 B
3 C
4 D
5 A
6 B
7 C
8 D
9 A
10 B
11 C
12 D
```

i.e. I need the output in this format of lines [A B C D, A B C D, A B C D]

I tried below code but its not helping me out

```
f = open("demoFile.txt", "r")

for line in f:
   with open("demoFile.txt", 'r') as infile:
    lines = [line for line in infile][:4]
    print(lines)
```

Comment: You expected output is not valid Python. Also, it would be easier to understand it with simpler fake data rather than these lines that look a lot alike...

Comment: Thanks for your inputs i have done the same

Comment: Does the input file has the numbers?

Comment: That is much easier to read, but the expected output still isn't valid. Do you mean a list of strings like `['A B C D'], ...]`?

Comment: yes, it does have number and special character too

Comment: I mean it has two tokens 1 A or is just A?

Comment: yes , exactly, need in the format [1-4,5-8,9-12] lines

Comment: Just A, 1,2,3,4 are line numbers

Comment: 1
2
3 are line numbers since input file is txt file

Comment: So to be perfectly clear, you want `["A B C D", "A B C D", "A B C D"]`, with the components (A, B, C and D) delimited by a single space, and you want each cluster (which we could call a record) to be a string element in an array. Is that correct? And the line numbers you demonstrated are only there as metainformation, and are not actually part of any input or output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like the generator defined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/312464/9397585

Remember you first need to convert the file to a list.

Your code should look like this:

```
f = [line for line in open("demoFile.txt", "r")]

lines = []

for i in range(0, len(f), 4):
    lines.append(f[i:i + 4])

print(lines)
```

Comment: And if you want a list of strings (with the 4 lines together) rather than a list of lists, use str.join(f[i:i+4]) inside lines.append().

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you could use the grouper [recipe](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) from itertools:

```
from itertools import zip_longest


def grouper(iterable, n, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper('ABCDEFG', 3, 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return zip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)


with open('data.txt') as infile:
    groups = [' '.join(group) for group in grouper(map(str.rstrip, infile), 4)]
    print(groups)
```

**Output**

```
['A B C D', 'A B C D', 'A B C D']
```

Notice that you can change the output to a list of list like this, for example:

```
groups = [list(group) for group in grouper(map(str.rstrip, infile), 4)]
```

This will return this instead:

```
[['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']]
```